# Visual Studio Professional 2013 requires up to 10GB across all drives...even HP_TOOLS(F:)?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I'm using HP ProBook 4520s and I'm trying to install Visual Studio Professional 2013 on Windows 7. I have not advanced my installation because I reached a window that says, "Setup requires up to 10GB across all drives."

In My Computer I have:

Local Disk (C:) 109 GB free,

HP_TOOLS (F:) 1.48 GB free of 1.98 GB,

and Paging Partition (K:) 12.1 GB free of 14.9 GB.

I assume that if I go ahead with the installation that not all components will install correctly due to the F: drive and the Paging Partition having limited space(it *says* 12.1GB are free, but maybe *in reality* 9.99?). So what solutions are available so I can install VS 2013 on my PC? Maybe [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does **not** mean you need that space *on each drive*. That would be stupid. It means it needs that space *once* and probably some of it on the drive you install too and some of it on your system drive.

Go ahead and install it.

Comment: Am installing it now. Will update you when it's done.

Comment: To be fair to Keegs, the wording "across all drives" is pretty misleading, I can understand the query.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it will install everything on C: and won't use any space on the other drives.

The warning is aimed at users who want to install to a non-system drive, (ie not the C: drive).  In those cases it will install some data to the C: drive and some data to the drive that was selected for installation.

The same seems to apply for Visual Studio 2015 too.